# How do I unit test a custom CacheInterceptor from NestJS?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nestjs

I wrote an own `CacheInterceptor` to cache POST requests as well and take the Accept-Language header into account. Of course I want to unit test it, but I don't know how to properly do so, since the `trackBy` method needs an `ExecutionContext` and the method uses the `httpAdapterHost` and `reflector` fields.
Has anybody done this before and knows how to achieve full test coverage?

EDIT: Here is the code of the CacheInterceptor

```js
import {
    CACHE_KEY_METADATA,
    CacheInterceptor,
    ExecutionContext,
    Injectable,
} from '@nestjs/common';

import { createHash } from 'crypto';

@Injectable()
export class MyCacheInterceptor extends CacheInterceptor {
    trackBy(context: ExecutionContext): string | undefined {
        const httpAdapter = this.httpAdapterHost.httpAdapter;
        const cacheMetadata = this.reflector.get(CACHE_KEY_METADATA, context.getHandler());

        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

        return [
            cacheMetadata,
            httpAdapter.getRequestUrl(request),
            JSON.stringify(request.body),
            request.headers['accept-language'],
        ]
            .reduce(
                (hash, somethingToHash) => (
                    hash.update(
                        somethingToHash
                            ? Buffer.from(somethingToHash)
                            : Buffer.alloc(0)
                    )
                ),
                createHash('md5'),
            )
            .digest('hex');
    }
}
```

Comment: edited my answer using the code you provided :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please bear in mind that the following example is testing the interceptor in isolation. Some tweaks may be needed for your use case, but the overall approach should be valid.

1. I would inject the cache and reflector dependencies using the constructor:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyCacheInterceptor extends CacheInterceptor {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) protected readonly cacheManager: Cache,
    @Inject(Reflector) protected readonly reflector: Reflector
  ) {
    super(cacheManager, reflector);
  }

  trackBy(context: ExecutionContext): string | undefined {

// ...
// ...
```

2. Your tests could look like:

```js
describe("MyCacheInterceptor", () => {
  let interceptor: MyCacheInterceptor;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [CacheModule.register()],
      providers: [
        { provide: CACHE_MANAGER, useValue: {} },
        { provide: Reflector, useValue: { get: () => "hello" } },
        MyCacheInterceptor,
      ],
    }).compile();

    // see issue: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/8076
    module.createNestApplication();

    interceptor = module.get(MyCacheInterceptor);
  });

  it("creates", () => {
    expect(interceptor).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("tracks something", () => {
    const mockExecutionContext: ExecutionContext = createMock<ExecutionContext>(
      {
        getHandler: () => ({}),
        switchToHttp: () => ({
          getRequest: () => ({
            url: "/test-url",
            originalUrl: "/test-url",
            method: "GET",
            body: {
              someKey: "someValue",
            },
            headers: {
              "accept-language": "en",
            },
          }),
        }),
      }
    );

    const result = interceptor.trackBy(mockExecutionContext);

    expect(result).toBe("d4f8ad8ba612cda9a5fda09cc244120c");
  });
});
```

3. There is a way of mocking `httpAdapterHost` (as well as `cacheManager` and `reflector`):

```js
(interceptor["httpAdapterHost"] as any) = {
  httpAdapter: { getRequestUrl: () => "hello" },
};
```

I consider this an anti-pattern, because you shouldn't be mocking/spying on internal methods and properties. However, if you check [this](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/8076) GitHub issue, you'll see that there isn't a good or proper way of mocking an `HttpAdapterHost`, so in this case it may be a good rule to break.

4. `createMock` comes from `@golevelup/ts-jest`

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. In this particular case, createMock wasn't necessary.